# C++ Overloading Operator<< By Using Static Helper Methods Creating Access Violation Error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, static-methods

I have a class called `Bill`. Among the properties of the class there is one called `category` of type `int`. 
When printing the Bill there should be displayed the name of the category instead of the number. So I wrote this static helper function to convert the `category` integer to the corresponding string:

```
// Takes an integer representing the category and returns its corresponding name
static const std::string& getCategoryByNumber(int category)
{
    switch (category)
    {
    case 1:
        return "Food";
    case 2:
        return "Gift";
    case 3:
        return "Fuel";
    case 4:
        return "Electricity";
    case 5:
        return "Clothes";
    case 6:
        return "Holidays";
    case 7:
        return "Water";
    case 8:
        return "Fees";
    default:
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Now I tried to overload the `operator<<` outside of the `Bill` class definition like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Bill& bill) {
    int category = bill.getCategory();
    const std::string& nameOfCategory = getCategoryByNumber(category);
    std::cout << nameOfCategory.c_str();
    return os;
}
```

[image: Shows debugging error]

The error occurs when creating an object of type bill and running this line of code:
`cout << billObject;`

If this are not enough information I'll be glad to add more.
How can I solve this error and what is causing it?

Comment: `std::string&` -> `std::string`

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @iehrlich Such stuff is inspectable with a debugger. Where does your assumption the OP is _an inexperiened programmer_ come from?

Comment: Off topic: consider replacing that switch with a `std::string` array. The you can `return categoryStrings[category];`(maybe `category-1` if you can't afford a string's worth of RAM for the wasted 0 element) and a test to ensure category is in range.

Comment: `"Food"` is not a `string`. It's constant array of characters. The compiler will automatically and silently create a `string` based on the `char` array  because `string` is required and `string` has a `char` array conversion constructor. Unfortunately this manufactured `string` is an Automatic variable (AKA a local or temporary) and will go out of scope and be destroyed almost immediately and certainly before you get a chance to use it. End result is the caller gets a reference to a dead variable.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for the explanation. I knew that e.g. "Food" is a `const char*` array but didn't think that could cause any trouble because the compiler was fine with that.

Comment: Important fun fact: The C++ compiler is "fine" with a lot of things that will get you into trouble. Compiler error = bad syntax. Source code cannot be transformed into program. Compiler Warning = Syntax OK. Source code can be transformed into program, but the program will do something questionable. This mistake may have triggered a compiler warning. If not, turn up the compiler warning level. It's your first line of defense. The classic example is `if (x=1)`. This is 100% valid C++ code, but it assigns rather than the compare likely desired. Compiles, but typically generates a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess of what really happens here, is the compiler creates an `std::string` object from a C string in the context of `getCategoryByNumber` function, returns a reference to it, and the object it references is removed right away once the function returns.

Please consider returning `const char*` or `std::string` instead of `std::string&` from `getCategoryByNumber`.

Comment: For you note, when the function ends the destructor for the temporary string that was created is called.  After it runs the objects lifetime has ended  and trying to use a object after its lifetime ends is UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver this repeats my answer except for the remark. The remark is here for a reason - instant dereferencing of destructed objects might accidentally work, for example, in debuggers, which use more cautious memory layout than usual runtimes. Happened to me like a week ago or so. It's really nasty when your application fails in plain run, but works under GDB, right?

Comment: I guess your downvotes come from the first and third lines, you should read them back over :)

Comment: @George, I re-read my answer for like 5 times, and I still don't understand what's wrong with it... Well, shame on me then, looks like I can't English today. Anyway, thanks for the feedback...

Comment: Doing `return std::string("Food");` is the exact same thing the compiler is doing for the OP automatically and will lead to the exact same behavior.

Comment: @iehrlich "while in fact it returns const char*." is not correct, the function would return a `std::string&`. And `return std::string("Food");` wouldn't make a difference, you'd still be returning a reference to a temporary.

Comment: @all, yeah that makes sense, my wording is actually bad. Anyway, I edited the answer, hope it's better now. Once again, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler should have warned you about "returning reference to local object" or similar (if you switch all the warnings on, which you always should). You should also avoid calling `exit()`, but instead `throw` an exception to give the application program a chance to recover

```
struct Bill
{
  /* ... */
  int GetCategory() const;
  static string GetCategoryName(int category)
  {
    switch (category) {
    default: throw std::runtime_error("Bill: category '"+
                                      std::to_string(category)+"' unknown");
    case 1: return "Food";
    case 2: return "Gift";
    case 3: return "Fuel";
    case 4: return "Electricity";
    case 5: return "Clothes";
    case 6: return "Holidays";
    case 7: return "Water";
    case 8: return "Fees";
    }
  }
};

inline
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, Bill const&bill)
{
  return os << Bill::GetCategoryName(bill.GetCategory());
}
```

Comment: Upvote for the exception. For those of you reading later, not only can it be caught and handled, but if it isn't caught it often results in a usable, human readable error message printed out for the user. Far less frustrating than, "Why the #%@*^ did the program just crash?"